# Parse DateTime column from datatable that is bad

Tags: c#, datatable

I have converted a very large csv file to a datatable and now I am parsing each column.  I have run into a problem where the data in a specific column is not correct.  It is suppose to be a date, ie 1/19/2020, but it has 1/1/0001 so it is crashing my attempt to parse.  What I am attempting to do is to remove rows in the table before I write it back out.

```
DateTime checkDate = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0);
for(int i = dt.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
    DateTime AccountInformationDate = DateTime.Parse(row["AccountInformationDate"].ToString());

    if (DateTime.Compare(checkDate, AccountInformationDate) > 0)
    {
         row.Delete();
         counter_skipped++;
     }
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

I get an exception when it tries to parse the date.

Comment: That date refers to the lowest value of a DateTime object. A DateTime object can't be null so it uses the minimum value. This can happen where you've tried to convert a blank / null bit of data into a DateTime. If you have those and you don't want them, run a check against [DateTime.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=netframework-4.8) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParse` to check if the input is valid. This solution assumes that you only want to keep the rows with valid `DateTime` that is later than `checkDate`; adjust it to your needs as necessary.

```
DateTime checkDate = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0);
for(int i = dt.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
    DateTime AccountInformationDate;
    bool dateIsValid = DateTime.TryParse(row["AccountInformationDate"].ToString(), out AccountInformationDate);

    if (!dateIsValid || (dateIsValid && DateTime.Compare(checkDate, AccountInformationDate) > 0))
    {
         row.Delete();
         counter_skipped++;
     }
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse) to check whether the date string is correct.